# install papercut to monitor and control network printing

Tags: networking, printing, administration, papercut

i am trying to install papercut. I am reading a big part of documentation but i'm still confused.

i want to know what i should install exactly

- in side of a print server
- in side of workstations (computers)

**to manipulate all printer :  who's connected to  the network and which are connected by USB**

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basically, what the software does is to "monitor" all the print queues on the machine where it is installed. So, the best place for you to install it is on the print server, or in a computer that has some printer queues shared. Also, if you have printer queues in more than one "server", you can select one as the primary server, and install a "secondary server" on others, so those secondary servers will send all the printing information of the queues on it to the primary one.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @habibakessraoui I'm happy I could help you. Could you please select my answer as helpful? Best of luck in your business.